# DATEDIFF() Not Calculating Number of Years Correctly

Tags: calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

Using 10/1/2008 as the "HireDate" field, the calculated "Number of   Years" returns 9 years when it should clearly be 10 years.

Using 8/1/1988 as the "HireDate" field, the calculated "Number of Years" is    29 years when it should be 30.

Using 11/1/1983 as the "HireDate" field, the calculated "Number of Years" is 34 years when it should be 35 years.

I was thinking about just adding 1 to the year value but then people who have not worked a year yet would show as working for a year.

I really don't know what is happening. Here is the formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(HireDate,NOW(),"y")=0,"< year","")&IF(DATEDIF(HireDate,NOW(),"y")=1,"1 year","")&IF(DATEDIF(HireDate,NOW(),"y")>1,DATEDIF(HireDate,NOW(),"y")&" years","")
```

Comment: Actually when i was finding the years between two dates.....=DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"y").     This worked for me. Not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: Your formula as written also worked for me. I wonder if perhaps the Time portion returned by the NOW() function is messing with your return values (for example, not returning a full 1 for counting today). Have you tried changing the NOW() function to TODAY() instead?

Comment: Using TODAY() instead of NOW() worked!

Comment: Please post and accept the answer to your question citing C. Dennett's response. That way the question shows as answered. Thanks!

Comment: This worked, but it's not the root problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and discovered that calculated fields don’t update themselves until item itself is updated. So even if there is a formula in the calculated field by the next day it's already outdated and it won't recalculate until you update the field manually, simply open save and close. This is simply the way SharePoint works and I will have to find another way to represent this, maybe with a "view" that updates every time you look at it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Use TODAY over NOW

```
   =IF(DATEDIF(HireDate, TODAY(),"y")=0,"< year","")&IF(DATEDIF(HireDate, TODAY(),"y")=1,"1 year","")&IF(DATEDIF(HireDate, TODAY(),"y")>1,DATEDIF(HireDate, TODAY(),"y")&" years","")
```

**Today vs Now**

- TODAY uses DATE
- NOW uses DATE + Time

Comment: Again, this worked, but it's not the root problem. See my answer.